# what is the best way to remove non numeric characters from the beginning of a string?

Tags: javascript, string

In Javascript, what is the best way to remove non numeric characters from the beginning of a string?

```
-_1234d5fr
```

should ideally turn into

```
1234d5fr
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/^\D+/, '');
```

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), and [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

  - `\D` stands for non-digit characters
  - The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string
  - `+` is "one or more of"

Answer (score 5):

How about...

```
str = str.replace(/^[^0-9]+/, '');
```